# Mysql "memory usage" increasing and increasing

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a really big website built old fashioned with PHP & MYSQL.

I have more than 1,000 different queries in my website, on different PHP pages, and it's really hard to update all of them to MYSQLI.

I bought VPS server with 4GB RAM and in the past months I experience really slow page loads.

When I restart my server, everything runs smoothly, but after couple of hours/days the website is getting muchu slower with loading time of 3+ seconds for a page load. I notice that the **mysqld** service is increasing and increasing in memory usage, from 80MB on server restart it reached about 400MB and more of usage.

I put in the end of my index.php mysql_close() but it seem like the connection number still increasing.

**Questions**
What can cause unlimited increment in mysql memory usage?
Updating all my queries to MYSQLI may improve the performance?

Some information:

```
innodb_version
5.5.31
protocol_version
10
slave_type_conversions
version
5.5.31-log
version_comment
MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine
x86_64
version_compile_os
Linux
```

storage engine: Mixed (Somes tables are INNODB,some tables are MyISAM.
my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
max-connections=100000
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
thread_cache_size=5
table_open_cache=99390
sort_buffer_size=512M
read_rnd_buffer_size=512M
query_cache_size=512M
query_cache_limit = 16M
query_cache_type = 1
slow_query_log=1 
slow_query_log_file=slow_query_log.log # 
long_query_time=5
log-queries-not-using-indexes=1


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I have about ~6-7 queries running when I use `show processlist`

Comment: first of the first, when your site goes slow, in mysql console run `show processlist` query  from the root to see what's going on

Comment: I have a bunch of questions:  what version of MySQL?  What storage engine are you using?  What are the buffer settings in my.cnf?  How many sorts are you doing in your code?  Sorry - this question can't be answered based on your statements.  And MySQLI won't make much performance difference.

Comment: Updated my question with all these information, @TGray. I can't tell how much sort I'm doing, but not much I guess. My main problem is from a table with almost 300k rows when using SELECT and ORDER BY although the queries are for specific user_id.

Answer (score 3):

`max-connections=100000` -- Yikes!  Drop to 1000

`table_open_cache=99390` -- drop to, say, 2000

`sort_buffer_size=512M` -- drop to 1% of RAM, say, 40M

`read_rnd_buffer_size=512M` -- ditto

`query_cache_size=512M` -- too big; slows things down; drop to 40M

`long_query_time=5` -- not low enough to catch much; drop to 2

`log-queries-not-using-indexes=1` -- clutters the slowlog without providing much info; change to 0

You did not say which Engine you are using.  Read [*this*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-memory-allocation/) for advice on MyISAM and InnoDB.

1000 pages -- that's not too many.

Which web server?  If Apache, don't set `MaxClients` to more than 20.

**2022 postscript**: The `query_cache_size` and `query_cache_type` variables have been [removed from mySQL 8.0.3+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/added-deprecated-removed.html#optvars-removed).

Comment: I mentioned in my post that my tables are a mix of MyIsam and InnoDB. I've been reading this staff but it's really hard to take a decision about that.  Going to try your config, thanks. And it's apache

Comment: Mysqld keep getting bigger and bigger, like all opened connections are not closing, I have no idea why it's hapenning..

Comment: The memory usage for mysqld will grow until it hits some limit, then it will fluctuate slightly.  My suggestions are aimed at keeping that limit from being dangerously large.  Swapping is _terrible_ for MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean by Swapping?

Comment: When the running programs need more than the available RAM (4GB in our case), the operating system swaps out pieces to disk.  This slows things down, but it is better than crashing the system.  However, MySQL's usage of RAM assumes that there is no swapping, so performance suffers badly when it does happen.

Comment: 400MB is not really much.

Comment: Well my whole site begins to load slow for some reasons. haven't figured it out yet.. Happens only few houres after restarting my server

Comment: What operating system?  Look for how to monitor swapping.  Turn on MySQL's "slowlog" and set `long_query_time = 1`; that will help you find out if some query is the cause of the sluggishness.